# Target class [currentTenant] does not exist (Spatie/Multitenancy)

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I used Spatie/Multitenancy for my multitenant-app. When I accessed landlord domain, I got errors:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 
Target class [currentTenant] does not exist.
```

I discovered that this error was caused by setting request session `app($this->currentTenantContainerKey())->id`.
Code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Concerns\UsesMultitenancyConfig;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CustomEnsureValidTenantSession
{
    use UsesMultitenancyConfig;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $sessionKey = 'ensure_valid_tenant_session_tenant_id';

        if (! $request->session()->has($sessionKey)) {
            // dd($request->session()->get($sessionKey));
            $request->session()->put($sessionKey, app($this->currentTenantContainerKey())->id);

            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($request->session()->get($sessionKey) !== app($this->currentTenantContainerKey())->id) {
            return $this->handleInvalidTenantSession($request);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function handleInvalidTenantSession($request)
    {
        abort(Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Hoe can I set value to request session for landlord?

Comment: Where do you bind $this->currentTenantContainerKey() to the container?

Comment: This class is copied from \Spatie\Multitenancy\Http\Middleware\EnsureValidTenantSession class offered by Spatie Multitenancy. I assume it was looking for its container to be bound to that is why this error occurred when it couldn't be found. However, I could not figure it out how to fix it.

Comment: I added following code and error disappeared.                                                           $tenant = Tenant::current();
        // dd([$request->session()->get($sessionKey), app($this->currentTenantContainerKey())->id]);
        if (!$tenant) {
            return $next($request);
        }